# MAUI. ScrollView to end

Tags: xaml, .net-6.0, maui, c#-6.0, maui-windows

I have such a problem. I have some chat with an interlocutor in `Scrollview` and it is dynamically updated with new messages. Somehow I had to lower the chat down all the time. I called the following method for lowering: `Body.ScrollToAsync(0, Body.ContentSize.Height, true);` But at the first iteration it does not lower the chat, and at the second iteration it does not lower it to the end. My question is the following: **How do I always lower the chat to the end?**

C# code:

```
    namespace MessengerMAUI;

public partial class ChatProcessor : ContentView
{
    public ChatProcessor(string Name)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessagesGrid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
        MessagesGrid.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
        ChatName.Text = Name;
    }

    List<Bubble> Messages = new();

    public int LastMessageIndex = 0;

    private void SendButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DrawMessage(TextBox.Text, true);//Разкоменть это когда будешь писать соединение с сервером и закоменть то что ниже
        if (testSenderCheckBox.IsChecked)// HACK: UI Test "Кто отправляет сообщение"
        {
            DrawMessage(TextBox.Text, false);//Отправитель - собеседник
        }
        else
        {
            DrawMessage(TextBox.Text, true);//Отправитель - Я
        }
        TextBox.Text = "";//Очистка поля ввода
    }

    public async void DrawMessage(string message, bool IsMyMessage)//Adding Message like a bubble
    {
        if (message != null)
        {
            
            Messages.Add(new Bubble());
            Messages[LastMessageIndex].BubbleCreator(message, IsMyMessage);
            MessagesGrid.AddRowDefinition(new RowDefinition());
            MessagesGrid.Add(Messages[LastMessageIndex], 0, LastMessageIndex);
            Body.Content = MessagesGrid;//Update chat content

            Body.ScrollToAsync(0, Body.ContentSize.Height, true);//scrolling to end

            LastMessageIndex++;
        }
    }

    
}
```

XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MessengerMAUI.ChatProcessor">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="84"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="Header" 
            HeightRequest="84" 
            Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Text="Чат" 
                FontSize="32"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label x:Name="ChatName"
                Text="Test Name" 
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="End" 
                FontSize="32"
                FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollView x:Name="Body"  
            Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid x:Name="MessagesGrid">
                <!--Сюда генерируются диалоги (bubbles)-->
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
        <Grid x:Name="Footer"  
            Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="105"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="#272B2C" 
                Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Editor  x:Name="TextBox" 
                Grid.Column="0"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Editor.Keyboard>
                    <Keyboard x:FactoryMethod="Create">
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <KeyboardFlags>
                                CapitalizeSentence, Spellcheck, Suggestions
                            </KeyboardFlags>
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </Keyboard>
                </Editor.Keyboard>
            </Editor>
            <Button x:Name="SendButton" 
                Text="Отправить" 
                BackgroundColor="#0066DC" 
                TextColor="White" Clicked="SendButtonClicked" 
                Grid.Column="2"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="testSenderCheckBox"/> <!--Удали это, когда сделаешь общение с сервером-->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Remove ScrollView and the contained Grid. Use CollectionView with an ItemsSource instead.

Comment: (In your approach, ScrollView contains a single item, a Grid. Getting that grid to dynamically grow beyond screen size is a bit tricky. Avoid the problem, by using CollectionView, which includes scrolling support, and copes well with content larger than screen. Then you don’t need ScrollView, nor Grid.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to **scroll** to the last child of your `MessagesGrid` like below:

```
var lastChild = MessagesGrid.Children.LastOrDefault(); 
if (lastChild != null)
{
    //await Body.ScrollToAsync(0, MessagesGrid.Height, true);
      await Body.ScrollToAsync(MessagesGrid, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
}
```